# Saving an captured image to the local folder

Tags: c#, wpf, save, image

I am taking pictures and would like to save them  according to the time they were exactly taken.

I would also like to create a folder named /pictures in the current directory and save the pictures in that folder. This is done in C# & WPF.

This is my code:

```
Image newimage = new Image();
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(); 
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();

newimage.Source = Capture(true) // Take picture

myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"c:\" + 
           string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now) + ".jpg"); 
// Gives error: Could not find file 'c:\2013-05-26_04-40-25-AM.jpg'

myBitmapImage.EndInit();
newimage.Source = myBitmapImage;

newstackPanel.Children.Add(newimage);
```

Results in:
***ERROR***   Could not find file 'c:\2013-05-26_04-44-59-AM.jpg'.

Why is it trying to find a file VS just saving the file on the c:\ drive?

Comment: It's the other way around, but have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/313384/Convert-image-to-Bitmap-Image-in-WPF-in-Csharp . It may help.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that already but I still don't get how to fix the error.

Comment: What about `var newimage = new BitmapImage(...` (remove your 1st line)

Comment: @xterminal0 update question with full code how you get image and how you save image

Comment: @xterminal0 Please don't drastically change your question. The original question was about how to save an image to disk which you have answers to. If you have a new question, please create a new one instead of overwriting this. People looking at this question now will be confused because the question and answers doesn't match.

Comment: @xterminal0 I went ahead and reverted back to an earlier state. I'll be happy to help you with your other question if you create it as a new question (you can even put a link to it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to save the image to disk, then you should use the [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) class

```
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
var image = Capture(true); // Take picture
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

// Save the file to disk
var filename = String.Format("...");
using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
  encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

The above example creates a JPEG image, but you any encoder you want - WFP comes with [Png](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx), [Tiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapencoder.aspx), [Gif](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder.aspx), [Bmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bmpbitmapencoder.aspx) and [Wmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.wmpbitmapencoder.aspx) encoders built in.

Comment: +1, but as OP obviously wants to write a JPEG image, why not just write the sample code straightforward with JpegBitmapEncoder?

Comment: It may also be a bit confusing why the declarations of `encoder` and `image` are inside the using block, but `filename` is outside. I guess it would be easier to understand if only the Save call would be there.

Comment: I get the cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Uri'

Comment: @xterminal0 Why arent't you doing it as shown in this answer? Instead you assign the captured image to the `Source` property of an Image control. Are you also showing the image in your UI? If not, there is no need at all for an Image control. Anyway, if you assign to `newimage.Source`, you should also pass that to BitmapFrame.Create: `encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(newimage.Source));`

Comment: @Clemens: (re: where variables are declared) Well, filename obviously *has* to be outside but I agree about the others.. I've updated my answer

Comment: @IsakSavo Yes of course, that's what I meant. Thanks for editing.